# Python Beautifulsoup Scraper not scraping images

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the below code:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ""

page = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, verify=True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
images = soup.find_all("img")
for image in images:
    image_url = image['src']
    print(image_url)
    if url not in image_url:  #This is to identify absolute/relative links
        link = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, image_url)
    else:
        link = image_url
```

I am working my way through thousands of URLs that I have agreement to scrape images from. Nonetheless, the URLs for some images aren't being detected. An example of a URL that returns no links in below below:-

https://www.lerryn-cornwall.co.uk/

Checking the source view, there are image links such as:-

```
link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://primarysite-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/theme/LerrynCofEPrimarySchool/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
```

Any suggestions on handling every possible eventuality of image links in thousands of web pages? I'm thinking of instead of looking for the img['src'] tag, I simply process 'soup' and look for any strings containing '.png' for example and then append these to a list. Is there a better means?

Comment: That's because the image is not defined in the html DOM but in a css file with the `background` property: `background: url(container-home.jpg) center top no-repeat, url(container-tile.jpg) center top repeat-x;`

Comment: Thanks @johannchopin. How can I amend my code with this? Also as I'll be scraping quite a number of sites, is there a way to be more vague when handling CSS given that each site may vary? So I can identify any image URLs in a css?

Comment: You should target `link` tag

Answer (score 0):

As [@johannchopin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583669/johannchopin) said, you should scrape css files of each website too, you can find the css file url via the html by scraping link tags, then you need to search in the css file string the url for each image, although this url might be stored for example in the same directory as the css file or not, you should keep in mind that in the css file you'll only receieve the location of the file according to where the css file is stored. If the css file is stored in a seperate folder the location of the img file will look like this "../img/someimg.png" the ".." sign means upper directory, like you go back on explorer, it basically means switching directory to the parent directory of the current file. I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following `css` selector.check if that helps.

```
for item in soup.select('[href*=".png"],[src*=".png"]'):
    print(item)
```